# Is there a p5 callback available to fire a function AFTER the sketch has finished loading?

Tags: p5.js

As I understand it, all sketches begin to build after the window loads. How do I know when the sketches have completed loading, and how do I call a function when they have?

Basically I have an array of sketch names contained in an array:

```
var stageTypes = ['sketch1', 'sketch2']
```

I cycle through the array to build each one:

```
function buildStageNew () {

    stageTypes.forEach( function (stageType) {

      var currentBuild = p5Build(stageType);

      // Store all the sketches in a global window 
      // object so I can call them later if necessary
      window.stages[stageType] = currentBuild

   })

 }

function p5Build (stageType) {

  return new p5(

    function (sketch) { 

      sketch.setup = function () {

         sketch.createCanvas(700, 410)  
         sketch.rect(40,40,40,40)

       }


  }, stageType)
}
```

It doesn't actually build them all on the spot though... p5 stores them and then executes the actual sketch build on window load. I thought there would have been some sort of callback I can fire once the sketches have finished loading...

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in to P5.js for this. But can't you just track the loading yourself?

Comment: Ok, good to know that there isn't anything built in. Thing is, how exactly can I track the loading? I need a single function to fire once ALL of the sketches have been built. How can I track the loading if I can't fire a callback once the sketches have loaded?

Comment: Fire a function for each sketch, and in that function check if all of the sketches are loaded?

Comment: Yeap, that seems like a good idea. I'll implement it and pop the solution here. I was just hoping for an built in p5 callback that would do this. Thanks!